# mouse down event is not firing in IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser

I am trying to create an anchor with a mousedown event.

**My Code**

```
for (i = 0; i < userDetails.length; i++) {
                    var userProfileURL = "http://www.xyz.com/KLMS/UserProfile.aspx?userid=" + userDetails[i][1];
                    userTable += "<li><a href=\"" + userProfileURL + "\" onmousedown=\"StoreClickedURL(" + userId + ",'" + encodeURI(userInput) + "','" + encodeURI(userDetails[i][3]) + "')\" title='" + userDetails[i][2] + "'>" + userDetails[i][2] + "</a></li>";
                }
```

By using FireBug I inspect the anchor it is showing like this

```
<a href="http://www.xyz.com/PublicProfile.aspx?id=1088" onmousedown="StoreClickedURL(1,'physics','http://www.xyz.com/PublicProfile.aspx?id=1088')">http://www.xyz.com/PublicProfile.aspx?id=1088</a>
```

It is working in all browser except IE.
In IE also it is showing the same style anchor what I have mentioned above.

but not going to the function declared in the mousedown event.

Please help

thanks in advance.

Comment: try this:
<a href="javascript:StoreClickedURL(1,'physics','http://www.xyz.com/PublicProfile.aspx?id=1088');window.location = 'http://www.xyz.com/PublicProfile.aspx?id=1088'">http://www.xyz.com/PublicProfile.aspx?id=1088</a>

Comment: yes its working
thanks

can you explain why we have to add javascript before that function??

Comment: if you click on a link, the href element will be triggert. so if you have a javascript (onclick / onmousedown) event, both will be triggert. To deal with this you can write `href="javascript: ..."` to signal the browser he has to do some js-action. Normally the href-attribute is not triggering a javascript function. 

By the way: the same works in form-tags for example. `action="javascript: ..."`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
< a href="javascript:StoreClickedURL(1,'physics','xyz.com/PublicProfile.aspx?id=1088');window.location = 'xyz.com/PublicProfile.aspx?id=1088'">
```